# Hhen using Word, how to remove the leading point of a "title"?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

When you apply the style "title 1" to some words, there is always a point appear.
How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to clarify a bit. I'm not sure what you mean by a leading "point"

You might check to make sure you aren't somehow getting a bullet mixed in with the title style, that's the only thing that comes to mind off hand.